# Responsive CSS / Inline divs

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-float

I am trying to use CSS to put a `100% width div` across the page and then under that `div` 2 `div`s `inline` that are `50%` each each `10px padding` on all the `div`s and then as the page gets smaller make the two `50%` `div`s change to `100%`

here is what i have so far:

```
<style type="text/css">
body,html {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.outer {
    width:100%;
}
.topblock {
    width:100%;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
.block1 {
    width:48%;
    padding:1%;
    float:left;
    display:inline;
    border:1px solid black;
}
.block2 {
    width:48%;
    padding:1%;
    float:left;
    display:inline;
    border:1px solid black;
}
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">

<div class="topblock">
tickets
</div>

<div class="block1">
service orders
</div>

<div class="block2">
tickets 2
</div>

</div>
```

whats the best way to do this?

here is a fiddle also: http://jsfiddle.net/dd6Wb/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1st of all you don't need `display: inline;` when you are using `float: left;`. Secondly, when you are going for responsive designs, always make sure you use the snippet below

```
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

What will the above snippet do? Well, if you know the box model, it will just behave the opposite of that. Also, you care not clearing your floated elements, so you can use the below snippet to be used on parent element holding floating elements

```
.clear:after {
   content: "";
   display: table;
   clear: both;
}
```

Also, last but not the least, you need to use `@media` queries and change your `div` width's to `100%` in a defined resolution block of `@media`, this is known as break points.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dd6Wb/4/) (Resize the window to see the effect)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a media query for that:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
   .block1, .block2 {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/6XJYM/)

As a note: The border may make the element to big. Due to rounding issues in some browers like Safari the design may break on some window sizes. See [Mr. Alien's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18229284/1456376) for a solution on that.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the border is also taking place from the 100%.

```
making 48% width with 1% padding and 1 px border makes 50% + 1px.
```

This is one possible solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/dd6Wb/2/