# Responsive css adjacent circles with text inside and text centered above

Tags: css, text, geometry

I found a few questions and answers, for example [Responsive CSS circles that can hold centered content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14293719/responsive-css-circles-that-can-hold-centered-content) and [Responsive CSS / Inline divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18229169/responsive-css-inline-divs) that are close to what I need, but I need some modifications to the solutions.

I put together the following code:

**css**

```
.mission-vision-circles {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
-webkit-border-radius: 100px 100px 100px 100px;
-moz-border-radius: 100px 100px 100px 100px;
border-radius: 100px 100px 100px 100px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px #ddd;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px #ddd;
padding: 5px;
margin: 5px;
float: left;
text-align: center;
}

  .orange {
    border: 0px solid #E05900;
    background: #e05900;
}

.gray {
    border: 0px solid #796e67;
    background: #796e67;
}

.dark {
    border: 0px solid #333;
    background: #333;
}

.mvv-circles-text {
    color: #fff;
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    margin: 25% auto 0 auto;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="mission-vision-circles gray"><p class="mvv-circles-text">Personal growth</p></div>

    <div class="mission-vision-circles orange"><p class="mvv-circles-text">To see us all living our lives stretched beyond the limitations imposed by our minds.</p></div>

    <div class="mission-vision-circles dark"><p class="mvv-circles-text">To share stories and experiences about reframing limiting mindsets in order to help you get out of your own way.</p> </div>
```

First what I want to do, then what is happening with that I did.

I am working in a Genesis Theme for Wordpress. I have a sidebar. To the left of the side bar I have content that **I want to**:

1. include three circles that are adjacent to each other
2. each circle will be a different color
3. each circle will have text, with the second and third circles having one sentence and the first will have three short phrases that I want to show on separate lines in the circle
   I want to have text above each circle; Values, Mission, and Vision, respectively centered above each circle
4. because the site can be accessed from different devises, I want to be sure that it is appropriately responsive

**The issues with the code above**

1. I am wondering if I am approaching the code correctly
2. The first circle, the way I have it set up, is not putting the short phrases on separate lines in the circle
3. I have no idea how to put the text above the circles
4. On the iPad the third circle moves below the other two circles and the text that is below the circles flows up to the right of the second circle (I have only been able to test the code from my laptop, iPad, and my iPhone, but I want to be sure it works on other hand held devices)

If there are any recommendations for improvements, I willingly accept them.

Thanks

Comment: @San - are you asking if I tried your response? Not yet, but I will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add css media queries and control the size and the position of the circles.

try this
http://jsfiddle.net/23V3w/

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
 your font  style goes here

 }

@media screen and (max-width: 950px) {
your font  style goes here

 }


 @media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
 your font  style goes here


 }

 @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 your font  style goes here

}
```

Comment: I gave it a try and tested on the iPad. Something other than the height will need adjustment because the circles are not circles. They are more like rounded edges where the tops and bottoms of the circles are cut off. Also, in landscape on the iPad, the words below the circles are going in the place of the third circle and the third circle is going below the other two circles. I tested reducing the width and height, but that only put all three circles adjacent to each other. The words still come up to the line with the circles. I have not tested it on the iPhone.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Jr2A5/ I got the circles working. I had to play around with the numbers for the height and the borders. I need to figure out how to add padding for the text because it is touching the border of the circles, more so on the devices, than on the JSFiddle. Outstanding is place text above the circles. Perhaps I should create a new post for that topic.